# If [Get Variable] is equal to [Array]

Tags: php

I am trying to find easier and simple way to code a logic.

That is if one variable is equal to any key values in an array.

For instance:

```
$someArray = array("a","b","c");
If($_GET["foobar"] == $someArray) {
     return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
```

If the $_GET["foobar"] had a value of A, B, or C, the case would return true. If it was any other values, it would return false.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return in_array($_GET["foobar"], $someArray, true);
```

EDIT: Added optional `true` parameter.

Comment: I would further set the third - optional - parameter to `true` (in case you decide to add empty strings or 0 to `$someArray`). See the comments on the functions documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 3):

Rather than integer-indexed arrays, you can make use of associative arrays:

```
$someArray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 1);
if (isset($someArray[$_GET['foobar']])) {
    ...
}
```

If you don't like to type out all the array values or the values of $someArray need to stay as they are, you can use [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip):

```
$someArray = array('a', 'b', 'c');
...
$otherArray = array_flip($someArray);
if (isset($otherArray[$_GET['foobar']])) {
    ...
}
```

You can even store useful information in the values of the associative array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [in_array()](http://au.php.net/in_array) function. I'm pretty sure it's exactly what you are looking for. Here is the function in the code sample you provided.

```
$someArray = array("a","b","c");
if(in_array($_GET["foobar"],$someArray)) {
     return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: if capital `If` legal? Looks weird. And you should just return `in_array(...)` as that evaluates to a boolean anyway.

Comment: It's not my code, maybe the OP intends to add more instructions within the curly brackets.

Comment: It's my typo. Sorry if I add any confusion.