# if one array element similar to request variable, then how to fetch another elements of array

Tags: php, arrays, get, request

I am asking Similar question [compare request values to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807217/if-get-variable-is-equal-to-array) - it doesn't work to me, my scenario is totally different

```
    $mkt =   array(
        array( 
            'title' => "Photos", 
            'iconlink' => "http://example.com/xyz.png",
            'pkg' => 'test' 
        ),
        array( 
            'title' => "code",
            'iconlink' => "http://example.com/xyz.png",
            'pkg' => 'main' 
        ),
        array( 
            'title' => "code",
            'iconlink' => "http://example.com/xyz.png",
            'pkg' => 'main' 
        ));
```

I am having logic issue in this problem, problem is i am getting value via **$_REQUEST** variable and then i compare this request value to array pkg element. If comparison is true then i want to get another elements except to matched one. In this as suggested, i am using unset to remove the key of element which is matched and all array point to new variable, it working but not for first element of array, it shows **null** when i compare request variable to  first element of array:

```
 $mkt = array();
$newArray = $mkt;

foreach ($newArray as $key => $value ) {

    if (in_array($pn, $mkt, true)) {
        unset($newArray[$key]);
    }
}

$rand_ad = array_rand( $newArray, 1 );

echo json_encode( $newArray[$rand_ad] );
```

Please have a look on this issue very grateful to me.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop in each value, if `$pn` is equal with that loop's `pkg` then unset than `unset` that element:

```
$pn = 'main';
$newArray = $mkt;
foreach ($newArray as $key => $val) {
    if ($pn == $val['pkg']) {
        unset($newArray[$key]);
    }
}
echo json_encode($newArray);
// [{"title":"Photos","iconlink":"http:\/\/example.com\/xyz.png","pkg":"test"}]
```

Comment: lorga: Hey, Solution was awesome, but there was a problem, unset removed an array element when it comes for comparison, but for another element comparisons like **$pn = 'test'** after checking 'main' it shows null, array has doesn't show anything it shows null in array

Comment: You said you want to remove that part! `i want to get another elements except to matched one`

Comment: Updated my answer,m you just need to copy the main array.

Comment: lorga: yes i want another elements except the matched one, and  unset remove that element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17305/discussion-between-shihon-and-mihai-iorga)