# Snakes and Ladders AS3.. how can a movie clip climb a ladder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am having this problem in developing this snakes and ladders game and i am very much hoping that you guys can help me out. i already created the board and the avatar. only thing is i cant make the avatar move up the ladder, and move down with the snake. can somebody help me? i am very much desperate right now, and every help is appreciated, thank you  guys!

EDIT:

here's the code that i have written so far here are some of the codes I have written so far..

```
stop();

var xCoord:Array = [141,251,360,471,580,691,799,910,1019,1127,1238,1238,1127,1019,910,799,691,580,471,360,251,251,360,471,580,691,799,910,1019,1127,1238,1238,1127,1019,910,799,691,580,471,360,251,251,360,471,580,691,799,910,1019,1127,1238,1238,1127,1019,910,799,691,580,471,360,251,251,360,471,580,691,799,910,1019,1127,1238,1238,1127,1019,910,799,691,580,471,360,251,251,360,471,580,691,799,910,1019,1127,1238,1238,1127,1019,910,799,691,580,471,360,251];
var yCoord:Array = [675,670,670,670,670,670,670,670,670,670,670,602,602,602,602,602,602,602,602,602,602,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,534,466,466,466,466,466,466,466,466,466,466,399,399,399,399,399,399,399,399,399,399,331,331,331,331,331,331,331,331,331,331,262,262,262,262,262,262,262,262,262,262,195,195,195,195,195,195,195,195,195,195,127,127,127,127,127,127,127,127,127,127,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60];

var arrSquares:Array = new Array(xCoord.length);

var spaceIndex:Number = 0;

var delay:Number = 400;

var tm:Timer = new Timer(delay);
tm.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, mover);
tm.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, moveDone);

spinner.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSpin);
var total:Number =0;
function doSpin(mevt:MouseEvent):void {
var rn:Number = Math.round(5*Math.random()+1);

txtCount.text = String(rn);
total = total + rn;
txtTotal.text = String(total);



txtCount.visible = true;
spinner.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSpin);




tm.reset();
tm.repeatCount = rn;
tm.start();

}



function mover(tevt:TimerEvent):void {
spaceIndex = (spaceIndex+1)%(xCoord.length);
chip.x = xCoord[spaceIndex];
chip.y = yCoord[spaceIndex];



}


function moveDone(tevt:TimerEvent):void {
spinner.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSpin);
txtCount.visible = false;

}
```

i dont know where to put the if statement of executing the motion tween attached to the chip(avatar)

Answer (score 0):

Well here are my initial thoughts. I would create an animation with your character who you want to move up and down. To make it simple, make an animation for climbing, then one for falling. It's really easy to do, just use the tween option on the timeline after inserting your keyframes.

Looks like you've created your animations. Now, whether or not he slides up or falls down depends on where your snakes and ladders are. Only you know that, so at those particular spots on your board (for example, x = 200 and y = 200) we want the if statement to occur. But we only want it to occur after your avatar is done moving. Probably  create a new function and add the following to the mover function

```
var checkX:Number = chip.x;
var checkY:Number = chip.y
checkLandingSpace(checkX,checkY);
```

Now let's make a function checkLandingSpace which will check if we are on a shoot or ladder

```
       function checkLandingSpace(checkX:Number,checkY:Number):void
    {
         if (checkX = (your point) || (another point) //first check all x points...continue like this for all points where a ladder is...the || means or
         {
              if (checkY = (your points....etc)
              {
                   mc_avatarLadder.play(); //choose your instance name to be mc_avatar, then play the tween
              }
         }
    }
```

Or check this post for equating one variable to any element in an array  [If [Get Variable] is equal to [Array]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807217/if-get-variable-is-equal-to-array)

Now write the that for your ladder. Then do the exact same thing with all of your shoots points. Except, make a new animation with instance name mc_avatarShoot then just say mc_avatarShoot.play();

After that, make sure on the last frame for both instances, you just put in gotoAndStop(1); just to make sure it's ready next time you go to play the animation.

Of course, adjust your timer appropriately. This should pretty much do it, there might be a couple things to adjust for your own game, but follow this and understand it and you'll get it.

Comment: thanks! i am very much new to as3 although i have already watched soe easy to learn tutorials including a little bit of animation and some codes. i have tried putting some tween on my avatar. i execute the animation when the avatar is at the bottom of the ladder. i am intending to make it climb the ladder, but to no extent. or maybe, its just me? can you please hep me with the code?

Comment: sir, if you want, i can give the fla copy. :D

Comment: Either that or post some relevant code. Unfortunately I won't have my CS6 computer for a couple hours. If you can wait till then I can give you more details. Or you can post some of your code and I'll have a look at it on here, just edit your question =)

Comment: thanks for the help! but too bad, i dont get it ): and i havent backed up the original file so i guess, i messed things up. can you still fix it? im gonna send you the file. if it;s okay with you? actually its a school project, and im pretty desperate for answers. please? that would really mean a lot to me (: